# Where should I add style in jQuery plugin elements?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, coding-style

Is it considered good practice to add style to the elements generated by a jQuery plugin in the script itself, or an external stylesheet?

```
(function($) {
    $.myplugin= function(options) {
        var options = jQuery.extend({
            backgroundColor: '#0066cc',
            borderColor: '#003366',
            borderWidth: '1px',
            fontColor: '#66ccff'
            // etc...
        }, options);
        var html = '<div id="__plugin">...</div>';
        var $plugin= $(html).css({
                            'color': options.fontColor,
                            'background-color': options.backgroundColor
                            'border-color': options.borderColor,
                            'border-width': options.borderWidth,
                            'display': 'none'
                            // etc...                                
                        });         
        return $plugin.appendTo(document.body);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Should I take the approach above and let users of the plugin pass in parameters to customize the style, or should I eliminate the style elements and use an external stylesheet?

My gut reaction tells me I should use the latter, but I'm curious what the standard practice is, or if there even is one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't really include styles in your pluggins if you can help it. Best thing to do is to expose your html as parameters for your plugin. See this article on the matter:

http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/03/making-a-jquery-plugin-truly-customizable

James Padolsey is spot on!

Comment: +1 for the excellent link (jquery's extend method is nicely employed), and I agree with this answer if you want or need to put styling directly in your plugin. However, if you were to put it in an external stylesheet, keep in mind you'll be making your designers happy if they can tweak the look without having to ask a programmer... Plus, a site redesign later on down the road doesn't need to update the programming either.

Comment: Hmmm, perhaps my comment should have been a standalone answer?

Comment: @starsignleo: Thanks for the link. It was a great read and exactly what I was looking for.

@Funka: Thanks for the suggestion. You're right, you should add it as a separate answer so others can benefit from the feedback.